# Clojure multiplication gives strange results

Tags: math, clojure, floating-point, calculator, multiplication

For some reason, I'm getting strange results from a multiplication function. This is the program:

```
(ns scalc.core)

(defn add [numbers]
  (reduce + numbers))

(defn sub [numbers]
  (reduce - numbers))

(defn mul [numbers]
  (reduce * numbers))

(defn div [numbers]
  (reduce / numbers))

(defn numchoose []
  (let [nums (re-seq #"\d+" (read-line))]
    (map #(Float/parseFloat %) nums)))

(defn delegate []
  (println "What operation would you like to do?: ")
  (let [operation (read-line)]

    (when (= operation "add")
      (println "You chose to add.")
      (println "What numbers? ")
      (println (add (numchoose))))

    (when (= operation "mul")
      (println "You chose to multiply.")
      (println "What numbers? ")
      (println (mul (numchoose))))

    (when (= operation "div")
      (println "You chose to divide.")
      (println "What numbers? ")
      (println (div (numchoose))))

    (when (= operation "sub")
      (println "You chose to subtract.")
      (println "What numbers? ")
      (println (sub (numchoose))))))

(defn -main
  [& args]

  (delegate))
```

And these are my results:

```
 ~/clj/scalc 1/7 % lein trampoline run src/scalc/core.clj
What operation would you like to do?: 
mul
You chose to multiply.
What numbers? 
10 1.5 3
150.0
 ~/clj/scalc 1/7 % lein trampoline run src/scalc/core.clj
What operation would you like to do?: 
mul
You chose to multiply.
What numbers? 
654321 1.5
3271605.0
 ~/clj/scalc 1/7 % lein trampoline run src/scalc/core.clj
What operation would you like to do?: 
add
You chose to add.
What numbers? 
1 2 3 4 5 6
21.0
 ~/clj/scalc 1/7 % lein trampoline run src/scalc/core.clj
What operation would you like to do?: 
sub
You chose to subtract.
What numbers? 
100 90 4
6.0
 ~/clj/scalc 1/7 % lein trampoline run src/scalc/core.clj
What operation would you like to do?: 
div
You chose to divide.
What numbers? 
64 8 2
4.0
```

The only ones that are incorrect are the multiplications, and only when using decimals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression `"\d+"` that you use just matches sequence of digits, without allowing for the possibility of a decimal point.  So in the first multiplication example, `1.5` is processed as two separate numbers `1` and `5`, and the whole product is computed as `10 * 1 * 5 * 3`, which is `150`.  Similarly, for the second, you get `654321 * 1 * 5 = 3271605`.

Might it be better to split the result of `read-line` on whitespace instead of using `re-seq`?

Comment: Thanks. I understand, and I have replaced re-seq with split.